# Get int type from Database c#

Tags: c#, sql-server, forms

I'm trying to retrieve a piece of data which is of type `Int` from my database.

Here is my code:

```
using (SqlDataReader dr = query.ExecuteReader())
{
    bool success = dr.Read();

    if (success)
    {
        label7.Text = dr.GetInt32(0);
    }
}

con.Close();
```

This throws an error:

> Cannot convert type 'int' to 'string'.

Any idea how to fix this code?

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to assign a number to a property that only accepts strings... which is what the error is warning you about.

Convert the number to a string before assigning it to the `Label`.

```
label7.Text = Convert.ToString(dr.GetInt32(0));
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can't implicitly convert `int` to `string` types. You have to end it with a `ToString()` method:

```
label7.Text = dr.GetInt32(0).ToString();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are not planning to use this value anywhere else, but only for the `Label` then you could do,

```
label7.Text = dr.GetString(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert an 'int' to 'string' type either by -

```
label7.Text = string.Format("{0}", dr.GetInt32(0));
label7.Text = "" + dr.GetInt32(0);
label7.Text = string.Empty + dr.GetInt32(0);
```